# Python IndexError : list index out of range PushBullet

Tags: python, list, pushbullet

I have a problem, I need help. I want to use `PushBullet` in python but I got error.

Here my code:

```
from pushbullet import PushBullet
from pushbullet import device

apik="myapikey"
pb=PushBullet(apik)
de=pb.devices[0]
success, push = de.push_note("adsadasd","asdasdasd asd asd")
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gggg.py", line 6, in <module>
    de = pb.devices[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you don't have registered device.

Using `for` loop, you can push for multiple devices, and will not raise exception even though there's no device.

**A possible cause of this is wrong api key specified.**

```
from pushbullet import PushBullet
from pushbullet import device

apik = "myapikey"
pb = PushBullet(apik)
for de in pb.devices:
    success, push = de.push_note("adsadasd","asdasdasd asd asd")
```

If you want to push only to the first device, make sure that there is at least one device:

```
...
pb = PushBullet(apik)
if pb.devices:
    db = pb.devices[0]:
    success, push = de.push_note("adsadasd","asdasdasd asd asd")
```

Comment: Thank you i tried your codes now.I didn't get the error but it didn't work :( It not responding. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: @BerkayEraydin, Don't worry about English. Check that you're using the correct api key.

Comment: @BerkayEraydin, Also try print the `pb.devices`: `pb = PushBullet(apik); print(pb.devices)`

Comment: Ahh yes , i wrong wrote the api key.I again copy and paste api key and solved. Thank you. :)

Comment: @BerkayEraydin, Thank you for the feedback. I updated the answer accordingly.